# Error after compilation in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am getting an error after compilation. I am using Magento 1.9.0.1.

My website was running too slow so I have complied but after compilation my website (frontend as well as backend) has down and showing the same error. Please help me to rectify the same.

**Error**: `Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ecomventures/public_html/demo/includes/src/../lib/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='/home/ecomventures/public_html/demo/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ecomventures/public_html/demo/includes/src/Fontis_Australia_Model_Observer.php on line 23`

Comment: Looks like the dev of the module "Fontis Australia" did a bad job...

Comment: so what is the solution of the prblm??

Comment: Contact the dev / company and tell him about it. Or learn php... because the error is really self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `includes/config.php` in your root directory where your Magento files are located.

Open that up and change:

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

to

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
```

That will allow you to see your site again without the fatal errors.

Comment: No problem at all! If the answer helped you please consider voting it up and accepting it as the correct answer :)